Лучшие технологии совместимые с Java для создания прототипа приложения по использованию географических карт
Всем доброго времени суток! Я начал работу над своим пет-проектом для пополнения портфолио и пришёл к идее-мему о создании интерактивной карты Берлина, на которой пользователь будет видеть карту города, своё местоположение на ней, а также отмеченные зоны в которых запрещено курить (допустим, 100 метров в радиусе каждой школы)
Собираюсь писать приложение на Java; На этапе поиска необходимых технологий столкнулся со следующими вопросами:

Какие карты лучше всего использовать? (рассматриваю openstreetmap и places api)

Какой UI фреймворк легче всего было бы использовтаь? (рассматриваю JavaFX, в будущем было бы интересно в образовательных целях подтянуть JS, но для прототипа хочу быстрое/примитивное решение, чтобы можно было без проблем посмотреть как всё работает)


Заранее спасибо за советы!!!

Насчёт ui-фреймворка. Если пишете под desktop — то JavaFX однозначно лучший вариант. Swing, честно говоря, не очень. Он и не поддерживается больше, и с менеджерами расположения беда, они ужасны. В JavaFX, насколько я знаю, сам ui можно сделать с помощью XML-разметки. CSS-стили вставить можно, см. JavaFX CSS Reference Guide

имхо, юзкейс для десктопа как то за уши притянут. такое надо писать на андроиде, а там и вопрос с картой и ui сам собой решится.

Если нужно быстро, то можно использовать Vaadin, там есть встроенные UI для карт, сами карты OpenStreetMap, документации и примеров много в т.ч. как выделять определенные области.
